# How to draw a branch name to the console?

Tags: command-line, github

Is it possible to display the name of the branch in this place?

[image: screenshot here]

How is this done in git bash for windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [bash-completion](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) you can add `$(__git_ps1)`, if you use `"` you need to escape the command substitution.

```
# change these if you don't dig my colors!

NM="\[\033[0;1;37m\]"   #means no background and white lines
HI="\[\033[0;37m\]"     #change this for letter colors
SI="\[\033[38;5;202m\]" #this is for the current directory
GI="\[\033[38;5;220m\]" # Git branch color
NI="\[\033[0;1;30m\]"   #for @ symbol
IN="\[\033[0m\]"

PS1="${NM}[${HI}\u${NI}@${HI}\h ${SI}\w\$(__git_ps1 ' ${NM}(${GI}%s${NM})')${NM}]: ${IN}"
```